# Using JSON/AJAX information from getJSON to change the src of multiple iframes to include the videoIds taken from the YouTube API

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So, I require four YouTube Videos to show the latest videos from a channel on page load, and am doing this by using

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    var YouTubeAPI = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3.......>"
    $.getJSON( YouTubeAPI, function( data){
        $.each( data.items, function(i, item) {
            $(".youtube-player").attr('src', "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + items.id.videoId + "?controls=1&amp;amp;showinfo=1&amp;amp;rel=1");
    })
}
});
```

The issue here is that the iframes all display the fourth video, instead of each video from the JSON GET.

Now, when replacing the line starting `$(".youtube-player").....` with `(alert(item.id.videoId);` I get the required VideoIds in an alert, starting with the newest (0) ID.

Comment: In your loop you have `items.id` I think you need `item.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can use `eq()` to match same index of elements to data

```
 var $frames = $(".youtube-player");
  $.getJSON(YouTubeAPI, function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
      $frames.eq(i).attr('src', "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + item.id.videoId + "?controls=1&amp;amp;showinfo=1&amp;amp;rel=1");
    })
  })
```

Comment: $frames is undefined in my browser's console.

Comment: Fixed by changing to $(".youtube-player")